# Entity Framework. Code First. context errors when not using a constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I am new to Entity Framework. 
Working on an existing application that uses the *repository pattern*.
When the context was created in the get property (no constructor) we got sporadic errors relating to the `DbContext` in production and in load test 
while it worked fine in local.
The issues got resolved when we added a constructor to the context class and initialized the context in the constructor. 
It does the same thing as the getter. 
Unsure has to how that solved the problem.
Anyone has an idea as to what is the difference between creating the context in the constructor vs getter that solved these issues.
I have searched the web high and low.

Below are the errors we encountered:

1. The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
2. Not allowed to change the `ConnectionString` property. The connection's current state is closed.
3. `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` (the object here is the context).
4. further exception: `The context cannot be created while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of Dbcontext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

Below is the code:

**EF DbContext**

```
public partial class EFContext : DbContext, IContext
{
    public EFContext(): base("ConnectionStringName")
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<TEntity> entityname { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //entity classes configuration
        ConfigureEntity(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**MyContext**

```
public partial class MyContext :  IContext, IDisposable
{
    #region Private Members

    private bool _disposed;
    private EFContext efContext = null;


    public MyContext () //Constructor
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            string entityKey = "_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");

            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(entityKey))
            {
                efContext = new EFContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(entityKey, efContext);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            efContext = new EFContext();
        }
    }

    private EFContext Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {
                string entityKey = "_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");

                if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(entityKey))
                {
                    efContext = new EFContext();
                    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(entityKey, efContext);
                }
                return (EFContext)HttpContext.Current.Items[entityKey];
            }
            else
            {
                efContext = new EFContext();
                return efContext;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use the context from a property? Just instantiate it in constructor or my favorite approach, inject it into the constructor with DI and configure the needed life time previously. For me your class seems to be more complex than needed.

Comment: It is not necessary to instantiate the context in the property. But that is how it was done and it was cause of occasional errors. 
We have added the constructor, instantiated the context in the constructor and all the errors are gone. 
Need to understand as to why instantiating in the constructor works better.

Comment: All these exceptions are a tell-tale of multi-threading issues. I bet that multiple threads have access to one `MyContext` instance.

Comment: That is right, we understand that.  But what I am trying to understand is how is that adding the same block of code to the constructor solved the issue with the context getting shared.

Comment: Impossible to tell, not seeing how `MyContext` is used. Probably the timing of the (EF) context creation is subtly different. But the real issue here is multi-thread access to a (by definition) not thread-safe EF context. You *have* to fix that.